# Product ID is passed from ajax to servlet but somehow the value is null

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my servlet  I am taking product selected by user and passing the product ID to servlet via AJAX

```
@WebServlet("/productSelected")
public class ProductCompareAJAX extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String productCode=request.getParameter("productCode");
    System.out.print("Product Code"+productCode);
    Set <String>prodCodeList=new HashSet<String>();
    prodCodeList.add(productCode);
    System.out.println(prodCodeList.toString());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("sessionProductCode", prodCodeList);
    System.out.println("Value in session *************"+request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionProductCode").toString());
    //String sessionProdId=request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionProductCode").toString();
    String nextJSP = "jsp/index.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }
```

This ajax call is triggered when user selects a product from list

```
function addToCompare() {
    console.log("Product ID: "+ this.id);
    console.log("Product ID: "+ this.dataset.productId);
    var productCode;
   if($("input[id="+this.id+"]").is(':checked'))
       {

       //ajax call
       productCode=this.dataset.productId;
       alert(productCode);
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'productSelected',
           contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;',
           data: {productCode:"productCode"},
           cache: false,
           success: function (data) {
               alert("Success");
           }
         });

       // ajax call ends

       }
   else
       {
       alert("Not selected");
       }
}

$(function() {
    $('.productCheckbox').click(addToCompare);
    console.log("Document is ready");


});

//Output
Product Codenull[null]
Value in session *************[null]
```

Please let me know why am I getting the values as `null` inside my servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ajax` data option,you wrote as

```
data: {productCode:"productCode"},
```

so the value of `productCode` will always be *productCode*.

Change it as below:

```
data: {productCode:productCode},
```